# Variation on htaccess redirect in Apache web server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

My question is a variation on the htaccess redirect about which much has been posted here, thanks everyone for all your help over the years. I tried various coding and just cannot get this to work.  Need a permanent 301 redirect for this:

Redirect all traffic from `http://sub.domain.com` (both HTTP and HTTPS) to `http://www.domain.com/sub/` and have the new URL show with the latter URL where the "sub" is a subfolder on the server and also the name of the subdomain from which I am directing all traffic.

Tried:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^sub/ /sub%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: What do you mean by **and have the new URL show with the latter URL**

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located? What actually happens?

Comment: Presently the htaccess is located on the existing web site which is hosting Prestashop. I need to redirect visitors to the new web site. Old site is store.ufcinc.com, the new site on another server is www.ufcinc.com/store.  After I get this working I will put up a redirect page on a new host and point the old store.ufcinc.com to the new site/subfolder.

Comment: Guessing that a simple 301 would do it since the whole site needs to be redirected: Redirect 301 / http://www.domain.com/subfolder/

Comment: That is what I did, just used a 301 redirect for the whole site. Done.

Comment: Glad you got it working. You can post your solution as an "answer" (and accept it after a couple of days). FWIW I've added an answer with info as to why your initial attempt did not work.

Answer (score 0):

> Old site is `sub.example.com`, the new site **on another server** is `www.example.com/store`.

Since the new site is on another server, you may not need to check the `HTTP_HOST` at all. However, if you have other (sub)domains then you might.

In the .htaccess file in the root of the subdomain for the old site:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =sub.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/sub/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Note the redirect flag (`R=301`) that was missing from your initial attempt. Without this (and the absolute URL in the substitution) it will try to do an *internal rewrite* instead.